# How to deal with module conflicts ("anti-dependencies")?

Tags: hooks

I have a module that specifically doesn't work with another module. I want to know if there is a way to check if that module is enabled and abort installation for example or gray out the installation box so that my module can only be installed if that other module is disabled.

It's like inverse dependencies!

Is there any way of doing this *properly* in Drupal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The module just needs to implement [hook_requirements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7); a requirement could be that a module is not installed, and if the module returnes an error from `hook_requirements()`, then it will not be installed.

The module should implement code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  // Ensure translations don't break at install time
  $t = get_t();

  if ($phase == 'install') {
    if (module_exists('other_module')) {
      $requirements['mymodule'] = array(
        'title' => $t('My module'), 
        'value' => $t('My module is not compatible with Other module.'), 
        'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR, 
      );
    }
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`hook_requirements`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) for this. You specifically need to check for `$phase == 'install'`, and then return the proper array containing `REQUIREMENT_ERROR`.

The [Simpletest module](http://drupal.org/project/simpletest) for Drupal 6 has a good example of aborting installation if certain conditions aren't met.